# find duplication number in array using java

Tags: java, numbers, duplicates

I try to find duplicate number in array but i have one problem
if number in array that duplicated more than 2 number it will print like this

Dupicate number is :40

Dupicate number is :40

that not correct.
So, I just want to print only number that duplicate and how many they occur.
this my code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] x = {
        10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 25
    };

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i - 1] == x[i]) {
            System.out.println("Dupicate number is :" + x[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);

}
```

Comment: Oh, must the duplicates be also in sequence?, then my answer is wrong, of course

Answer (score 1):

Put the array members in an hashmap that keeps the count.
then iterate over the map. So you find also all duplicates.

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{

    int[] x = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 25 };
    Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
//      if (count.containsKey(x[i]) && (x[i] == x[i-1])  ) { 
//      use this if the duplicates must be consecutive
        if (count.containsKey(x[i])) {
            count.put(x[i], count.get(x[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            count.put(x[i], 1);
        }
    }
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : count.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
            System.out.println("Dupicate number is :" + entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue() + " occurences");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Added in comments the modification for consecutive duplications, but this finds only the last duplicate

Comment: `put(get() + 1)` means continually unboxed and reboxing the value. Using `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` would be better for performance. `int[1]` would be even better.

Comment: You're right, with some further thinking i would have made 1 boxing: Integer value = x{i]; and count.put(value,count.get(value)++).

Comment: Just did a small performance test. `AtomicInteger` is slightly better than boxing. `int[1]` runs in less than half the time of the other two, so `int[1]` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashSet` fro Java Util:

```
// x is name of your array
int[] x = {
    3, 4, 4, 5, 6
};
HashSet < Integer > mySet = new HashSet < Integer > ();
ArrayList < Integer > dlist = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

for (int val: x) {
    if (!mySet.add(val)) {
        dlist.add(val);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < dlist.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(dlist.get(i));
}
```

Now the newArr contains only non-repeated elements.

No. of duplicates = `x.length - newArr.length`

Comment: and how do you know which is the duplicate?

Comment: loop and check if it exists or not .Wait i'll add it to my code

Comment: But every value *will* exist.

Comment: I meant loop and check if every value exists only oncr

Comment: So you give an answer that doesn't actually answer/solve the question, then say to just "loop and check if every value exists only once" when the question is exactly about how to do that. In short, you haven't provided *anything* **useful** here. Question is: *How to find duplication numbers, and only print about each duplicate number once*

Comment: I'm too lazy. Wait I have to go to school now, I'll do it after I come home. @Andreas

Comment: @Andreas now, please don't tell print function is undefined

Comment: From question: *"I just want to print only number that duplicate and how many they occur"* Your new code will produce the same result that question already has and (to quote question again) *"that not correct"*.

Comment: @Andreas dude can thee check now !

Comment: How about *you* check, using original numbers from question. Then you'd know you *still* didn't get it.

Answer (score -1):

A practical solution would be using collections:
turn the array into a list,
the method   `Collections.frequency(a, b)` will return how oft b is present in the collection a, so you need to iterate the list and then populate a map with the result of that method

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 25 };
    List<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (int index = 0; index < x.length; index++) {
        myInts.add(x[index]);
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> ss = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < x.length; index++) {
        if (Collections.frequency(myInts, x[index]) > 1) {
            ss.put(x[index], Collections.frequency(myInts, x[index]));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ss);
}
```

that code  will print

> {40=3}

that is actually what you are looking for.

Comment: That's a *very* slow way to do it. For every element, call `frequency()`, which scans the entire list again, and if count is >1, then do *another* full scan to find the number you already got. `O(n^2)` *Yikes!*